# FPSE, folder permissions and SharePoint Designer

Tags: security, asp-classic, permissions, frontpage-extensions

All,

A few of our internal users are editing one of our classic ASP sites (Not a SharePoint site) via Sharepoint Designer which I believe uses FrontPage Server Extensions.

I would like to give a particular user author rights to a single folder - ie, /products and any items and folders it contains. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that VSS takes its permissions from those set through explorer/the file system. The permissions I had set on both the web folder and the VSS database folder had not propagated correctly, which caused the problem.